# Latex how I add local file pdf path \bibliographystyle{natdin}

Tags: pdf, latex, bibtex

I have a latex file with bib text file. I have the problem that I would like to add on my literatur add my local pdf path so that when i have my pdf file I can open it direktly from my local hard drive.

Latex:

`\bibliographystyle{natdin}
\bibliography{Literatur}`

example in my file "Literatur.bib":

```
@article{myarticle,
 author = {my autor},
 year = {2016},
 title = {my title},
 url = {http://myarticle.org/myarticle.pdf},
 urldate = {08.12.2016},
 file = {...\\myfolder\\12341234.pdf:pdf}
}
```

What I get:

```
my autor, 2016, my title, http://myarticle.org/myarticle.pdf
```

What I want:

```
my autor, 2016, my title, http://myarticle.org/myarticle.pdf, 12341234.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `note` field to hold an external `href` link, like so:

```
@article{myarticle,
 author = {my autor},
 year = {2016},
 title = {my title},
 url = {http://myarticle.org/myarticle.pdf},
 urldate = {08.12.2016},
 note = {\href{run:../myfolder/12341234.pdf}{12341234.pdf}},
}
```

Note the corrected path format. The result will be like this:
[image]